# Zend_Controller_Router_Route

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I'm trying to make a Router that can respond to this structure:

`module/controller/action/id` and `module/controller/action/page`

The only difference is is 'id' or 'page'. I'm using this code:

```
$routeAdmin = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'administrador/:controller/:action/:id/:pg',
  array(
    'module' => 'administrador',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'id' => 0,
    'pg' => 1
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '\d+',
    'pg' => '\d+'
  )
);
$router->addRoute('administrador', $routeAdmin);
```

The problem is that in some situations i want:

`'http://www.domain.cl/administrador/productos/2' => (module=>administrador, controller=>productos,page=>2)` but with the router 'administrador' result in `'http://www.domain.cl/administrador/productos/index/0/2' (module=>administrador, controller=>productos,action=>index,id=>0,page=>2)`

I'm very confused about how it works for cases like this. I tried to make two router where the first only have 'id' param and the other 'page' param. And from url helper use it like:

1. `$this->url(array('module' => 'administrador', 'controller' => 'productos', 'action' => 'index', 'id' => 0), 'administradorId');`
2. `$this->url(array('module' => 'administrador', 'controller' => 'productos', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => 1), 'administradorPg');`

But when I used the routers always select the last one added to the router (`$router->addRoute('routerIdentifier', $route);`)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue and I got around this by defining just one route like this

```
$routeAdmin = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'administrador/:controller/:action/:id/:pg',
  array(
    'module' => 'administrador',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'id' => 0
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '\d+'
  )
);
$router->addRoute('administrador', $routeAdmin);
```

In your `actions` you'd then need to get the `id` and check for it somewhere where that `id` might be, for example if you were in `/administrador/events/view/1` then you might look in the events table or if you were in `/administrador/pages/view/1` then you would look for a page.

But the problems really start when the `id` could be either an event or a page in a given controller and action. The only real way around this is explicitly set the type of `id` your using for example

```
/administrador/events/view/index/id/1
```

or

```
/administrador/pages/view/index/page/1
```

If you want to remove the index part then set up routes like

```
$routeAdmin = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  // Remove the action from here and explicitly set the controller
  'administrador/pages/:pg',
  array(
    'module' => 'administrador',
    'controller' => 'pages',
    // Then set the default action here
    'action' => 'index',
    'pg' => 0
  ),
  array(
    'pg' => '\d+'
  )
);
$router->addRoute('administradorpages', $routeAdmin);
```

What your asking for basically results in a lot of guess work and therefore risk of producing unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found a solution: in the url helper if you set the extra parameter equal the default value in the router, it works and dont assembly to the url.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [dynamic segments](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) in routes. It is not exactly what you want, but it might be helpful in your case.